# Best practices for porting a visual studio solution file to scons

Tags: build, scons

I'm new to scons and trying to port over an existing visual studio solution (.sln) which internally references many VS project files (.vcxproj). The are multiple outputs, including a variety of libraries, and different executables.

From a conceptual point of view I'm unsure if I'm going down the right path and would appreciate any advice on how to do it better.

Here is my setup:

I have a top level SConstruct file at the root of the code depot. Additionally I have one SConscript file for each of my old VS project files. The SConstruct file calls the SConscript function once for each of these SConscript files, in which it specifies the source directory and where the outputs should go as parameters.

Additionally the SConstruct file creates and passes to each SConstruct file an array of scons environment instances. For example, there is one for compiling libraries, one for compiling executables, one for debug config, one for release, etc. and each SConscript file then chooses the one it wants, based on what it's trying to accomplish.

There are a couple things which I was wondering about:
1) Is there a better approach than creating multiple different environments, one for each configuration variation? Is that the expected usage pattern?
2) In visual studio, I could right click on a specific project and select build to only build that project and the projects it depends on, ignoring the rest of the dependency graph in the sln. With scons, is it true that it'll recompute the entire dependency graph every time I trigger a build of a specific library, even though in theory it would only need to compute a little portion of the entire dependency graph.

Thanks for any advice.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to having a SConstruct call several subsidiary SConscript files is indeed a good way to organize your projects, and is called a [Hierarchical SCons build](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c3181.html).

Regarding your questions, here are some things to consider:

1. **Several different environments:** Unless you have different compilers or compiler flags per builder or target (library, executable, etc) I would say that the approach you are using is a bit overkill. You could most likely achieve the same with just one environment. If you do need additional flags per sub-directory/builder, then you could consider passing the "main" environment to the subdirs, and in the respective SConscript's, clone the env and add/append what you need as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366384/1158895). This way the entire solution will be more modular by avoiding repetition and keeping everything common in one central place.
2. **Building certain projects/targets:** You can do the same with SCons by selecting the target on the command line, like this `$ scons yourTarget`. You can make the target names more manageable using the [env.Alias()](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c4348.html) function. SCons does indeed analyze everything before building, but depending on the size of the project, it shouldnt be a problem, its still quite fast. If build performance does become an issue, [here](http://www.scons.org/wiki/GoFastButton) are some pointers for improving the performance.

Here are a few extra good things to know:

- The [SCons documentation](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/index.html) is not bad WRT to other open-source tools. At the bottom of that doc page, there are several appendices with lots of extra information. The [SCons man page](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html) is quite complete too.
- Paths can be confusing in SCons if you're not Using the '#' as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9807067/1158895)
- If you need to deal with MSVS projects, you can use the MSVSProject() and MSVSSolution() builers as mentioned [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/a8121.html).

Comment: Thanks Brady. Most of the examples I've seen seem to advocate the single env approach also. I can see how the multiple environment approach might quickly get out of hand.